# how to get the path of a displayed image in a webpage using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php

hello am taking an image using webcam in javasript and uploading the image to a directory .I want to link the image taken to the users name.how can i do that please .

Comment: Do you have the image already uploaded on a webserver that's running PHP?

Comment: the app is a messaging app that has 3 steps 1. providing all details and message 2. taking your image with the webcam and 3. sending .immediately you take the photo, its uploaded to the server automatically  but with the datetime name. want to change that to the users name.I have tried to use ajax but the file uploaded is an invalid image.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, if you know where the image in relation to the php file on the server (like if image is in image/uploads and the php file is in php/pages) you can run the following in your php file:

```
    $username = "bob33";
    $currentTimestamp = time();
    shell_exec("mv ../../images/uploads/" . currentTimestamp . " ../../images/uploads/" . $username);
```

A better way to do this however (since you can't guarantee the timestamp will be the same as the instant the shot is saved and this screws up with multiple users is to alter the code that actually takes the screenshot to give it a userid value or some kind of token that you associate with a user in a database table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Antoine Dahan. I havent tried your method but yesterday I rolled up my head and got how to go aound it.I put all the webcam and ajax code in one js file then store the name of the snapshot in a parmanent js variable then send it via ajax and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

This has used multistep form with 3 steps, validation, webcam and ajax xmlhttpRequest to communicate to the sever

```
webcam.set_api_url('upload.php');
webcam.set_quality(90);
webcam.set_shutter_sound(true);

webcam.set_hook('onComplete', 'handleOnComplete');

function takePhoto() {
document.getElementById('imageDiv').innerHTML ='<img src="uploading.gif">';
webcam.snap();
}

function handleOnComplete(msg) {
if (msg.match(/(http\:\/\/\S+)/)) {
    var image_url = RegExp.$1;
//this image_url is waht will be sent to the server////
    document.getElementById('imageDiv').innerHTML = '<img src="'
            + image_url + '">';
        var myurl=image_url;
//down here am storing the image_url variable parmanent to be accessed            outside the function by ajax ////
        localStorage.setItem('myfix',myurl);
    webcam.reset();
        simage =localStorage.getItem('myfix');
} else
    alert(" Error Occured when capturing image: " + image_url);
}
//////////////////////////////
/**
 * 
 */
var firstname, secondname, email, phonenumber
subject, message, image;
/**
 * 
 * @param divname
 * @returns The div content without the value.
 */
function getDivValues(divname) {
return document.getElementById(divname);
}
/**
 * processes the first step of the form.
 */
function processStep1() {
firstname = getDivValues('firstname').value.trim();
secondname = getDivValues('secondname').value.trim();
email = getDivValues('email').value.trim();
phonenumber = getDivValues('phonenumber').value.trim();
subject = getDivValues('subject').value.trim();
message = getDivValues('textmessage').value.trim();
if (firstname && secondname && email && phonenumber && subject && message) {

    getDivValues('step1').style.display = 'none';
    getDivValues('step2').style.display = 'block';
    getDivValues('progressbar').value = 50;
    getDivValues('status').innerHTML = 'step 2 of 3';

} else {
    alert('kindly provide all details');
}

}
function processStep2() {
image = getDivValues('imageDiv').innerHTML;
if (image.trim() !== '') {
    getDivValues('step2').style.display = 'none';
    getDivValues('showpreview').style.display = 'block';
    getDivValues('showfname').innerHTML = firstname;
    getDivValues('showsname').innerHTML = secondname;
    getDivValues('showemail').innerHTML = email;
    getDivValues('showphonenumber').innerHTML = phonenumber;
    getDivValues('showsubject').innerHTML = subject;
    getDivValues('showmessage').innerHTML = message;
    getDivValues('showphoto').innerHTML = image;
    getDivValues('progressbar').value = 100;
    getDivValues('status').innerHTML = 'STEP 3 of 3';
} else {
    alert('please take a photo to proceed');
}
}
function reverseStep2() {
getDivValues('showpreview').style.display = 'none';
getDivValues('step2').style.display = 'none';
getDivValues('step1').style.display = 'block';
getDivValues('progressbar').value = 0;
getDivValues('status').innerHTML = 'STEP 1 of 3';

}
function cancelSubmission() {
getDivValues('response').style.display = 'none';
getDivValues('step1').style.display = 'block';
getDivValues('showpreview').style.display = 'none';
getDivValues('step2').style.display = 'none';
getDivValues('progressbar').value = 0;
getDivValues('status').innerHTML = 'STEP 1 of 3';
$('#firstname').val('');
$('#secondname').val('');
$('#subject').val('');
$('#textmessage').val('');
$('#email').val('');
$('#phonenumber').val('');

}

function submitForm() {
getDivValues('webcam_multiphase').method = 'post';
getDivValues('webcam_multiphase').action = 'userdata.php';

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        getDivValues('response').style.display = 'block';
        getDivValues('response').innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
        getDivValues('showpreview').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
sfname = 'firstname=' + firstname;
ssecondname = 'secondname=' + secondname;
semail = 'email=' + email;
sphonenumber = 'phonenumber=' + phonenumber;
ssubject = 'subject=' + subject;
smessage = 'message=' + message;
ssimage = 'imagepath=' + simage;
phpvariables = sfname + '&' + ssecondname + '&' + semail + '&'
        + sphonenumber + '&' + ssubject + '&' + smessage+'&'+ssimage;
xmlhttp.open('post', 'userdata.php', true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',
        'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send(phpvariables);
//window.location.href = 'messageboard.php';
}
function isString(fieldname) {
$('.error').remove();
$('.success').remove();
var stringMatch = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
if (!$(fieldname).val().match(stringMatch)) {
    $(fieldname).after(
            '<span class="error">please supply letters only</span>');
    $(fieldname).val('');
} else {
    $(fieldname)
            .after('<span class="success"><img src="passed.png"</span>');
}
}

function isEmail(fieldname) {
$('.error').remove();
$('.success').remove();
var emailMatch = /^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i;
if (!$(fieldname).val().match(emailMatch)) {
    $(fieldname).after(
            '<span class="error">type a correct email address</span>');
} else {
    $(fieldname)
            .after('<span class="success"><img src="passed.png"</span>');
}
}

function isNumber(fieldname) {
$('.error').remove();
$('.success').remove();
var numberMatch = /^\d+$/;
if (!$(fieldname).val().match(numberMatch)) {
    $(fieldname).after(
            '<span class="error">please supply numbers only</span>');
    $(fieldname).val('');
} else {
    $(fieldname)
            .after('<span class="success"><img src="passed.png"</span>');
}
}
```